# Python - sudden slowdown in Pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory, pygame

I am writing a 3D engine in Python using Pygame. For the first 300 or so frames, it takes from about 0.004 to 0.006 seconds to render 140 polygons. But after that, it suddenly takes an average of about 0.020 seconds to do the same task. This is concerning to me because this is a small-scale test, and even though 50 FPS is decent, it cannot be sustained at 1000 polygons, for instance.

I have already done a lot of streamlining to my code. I have also done some slightly deeper profiling, and it appears that the increased time is more or less proportionately distributed, which suggests that the problem is not specific to a single piece of code.

I assume that the problem has something to do with memory usage, but I do not know exactly why this problem is happening. What specific issue is causing this to happen, and how can I optimize my code to fix it, as well as some more general practices? Since my code is very long, it is posted [here](http://www.devtano.com/software/winkelman/pygame-3d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I can't answer your question exactly, I would use a task manager and watch the "python" (or "pygame" depending on your OS) process, and view it's memory consumption. If that turns out to be the issue, you could check to see what variables you don't need after a certain time, and then you could clear those variables.

Edit: Some CPUs have data loss prevention systems. What I mean by this is this:
If Application X takes up 40ish % of the CPU (it doesn't have to be that high). After a certain amount of time, the CPU will throttle the amount of CPU that Application X is allowed to use. This can cause slowdown for things such as this. This doesn't happen with (most) games because they're set up to tell the CPU to expect that amount of strain.

Comment: The nature of my program is essentially iterative. There are no variables that I can delete. I also ran my program again, watching memory. It stayed constant for a long time (at 17.1 MB), and only increased marginally (to 17.3 MB) after several minutes. Performance is also erratic because of how the computer has different processes going at different times. I think a number of modifications I have made since have fixed the problem accidentally. These mods are mostly in reducing new objects created.   Thanks for this advise.

Comment: Actually, the problem is still there on a larger scale, but there is again no dramatic increase in memory usage.

Comment: @bcdan strange. What about CPU usage?

Comment: When it is working properly, CPU is 25-35%. When it slows down, CPU goes to <10%, and loses a proportionate number of FPS.

Comment: Do you think that your CPU might have a feature that tones back performance after a certain amount of time?

Comment: It would seem logical, some CPUs have a thing where once an application starts to use too much CPU for too long, it will start to throttle the application.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks again for your answer. Would you consider adding this information to your answer for future users?

Comment: This seems to be what is wrong. Thanks for your time.